# cubic surface equation

Tags: projective-geometry, projective-space

If $[1,0,0,],[0,1,0],[0,0,1],[1,1,1],[1,3,2],[1,4,3]$ are six points on $P^2$ in general position and $f_0, f_1, f_2, f_3$ are the generators of the four dimensional vector space generated by cubics through the six points as :

$f_0= x_0[-16(x_0)(x_1) + 18(x_0)(x_2) + 4(x_1)^2 - 6(x_2)^2]$,

$f_1= x_0[-6(x_0)(x_1) + 7(x_0)(x_2) - 5(x_2)^2 + 4(x_1)(x_2)]$,

$f_2= - 6(x_0)^2(x_1) + 31(x_0)^2(x_2) - 29(x_0)(x_2)^2 + 4(x_1)^2(x_2)$,

$f_3=  6(x_0)^2(x_1) + 13(x_0)^2(x_2) - 23(x_0)(x_2)^2 + 4(x_1)(x_2)^2$

Define the map $P^2\setminus\{P1,...,P6\}\to P^3$ by
                            $P\to[f_0(p),f_1(p),f_2(p),f_3(p)]$

the image of this map stays on a cubic surface of $P^3$.
So, how can get the equation of cubic surface of this image?

any help is appreciate,
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You need to learn how to format math for this site. There is a useful guide here http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation The key point is that the math parts need to be between \$ symbols. In the meantime I have done some quick basic editing. Does that look correct?

Comment: you can always get an equation with brute force computation and lots of linear algebra.

Answer (score 1):

A cubic in $P^3$ has $20$ monomials, so it is uniquely defined by $19$ points in general position. So take $19$ points in general position, plug them into the polynomials, compute all cubic monomials and build a matrix from that. Then determine the kernel of said matrix, which should be one-dimensional. To make things easy, randomly generate a good measure of additional points so you won't have to worry about general position. The resulting matrix should have rank $19$, then it's fine.

Using this approach (and $30$ randomly generated points) I found the resulting cubic to be

\begin{align*}
6f_0^2f_1 - 23f_0f_1^2 + 70f_1^3 - 32f_1^2f_2 + 4f_1f_2^2 + 6f_0^2f_3\\
- 14f_0f_1f_3 + 36f_1^2f_3 - 4f_0f_2f_3 + 5f_0f_3^2 - 6f_1f_3^2&=0
\end{align*}